# UK visa delayed for more than usual

Tags: visas

I applied for UK Visa in August 28, 2018, in Accra Ghana, and in a week or two weeks later received a letter from them stating this below:

> Dear  .........................
>
> Thank you for your visa/entry clearance application which has been
>   received and is under consideration.  We aim to process non settlement
>   applications within 15 working days and settlement applications within
>   60 working days (unless you have opted for a Priority Visa service).
>
> We are unable to resolve your application within these customer
>   service targets, as the processing of your application has not been
>   straightforward. Please be assured that we will continue to progress
>   your application to enable a decision to be made as soon as possible.
>
> Please do not attend the application centre until you have been
>   contacted by the VAC.
>
> Kind regards Croydon DMC

Now after this email, I didn't hear from them again until last 3 weeks I contacted them on phone which I paid with credit card before talking to me and apologising for the delay and they said this below:

> Dear................
>
> Thank you for contacting UK Visas and Immigration International
>   Contact Centre. Accept our apologies for the delay in processing your
>   application
>
> I have escalated your case to the relevant department. Please allow 15
>   working days to pass before contacting UK Visas & Immigration
>   International Contact Centre again should you not receive any further
>   correspondence.
>
> Your patience is much appreciated.
>
> Regards,
>
> Abdulai UK Visas and Immigration

So after talks with them, it's been three weeks after this conversation but still haven't heard from them and today is 19th January, 2019 and applied the unbiased on 28th August, 2019.

Now guys I want to withdraw the application and demand a refund of my application on this coming Monday 21st January, 2019. Because they won't process the application and it will keep delaying and I need my passport to travel for a work related in South Africa and Botswana by next month.

But also feels I should give them some time and it will come successful, or could it be my passport is lost with them?

Comment: I got this same exact mail word for word, only i'm from Lagos, Nigeria and i only just applied last week, plus mine is priority. How far have they gone on yours?

Answer (score 3):

You should request your passport back and demand a refund **and** complain to higher authority. You can try complaints@homeoffice.gov.uk to complain

You can’t wait and keep **hoping**, hope is not a winning strategy. Something is clearly wrong.

They claim they process [100% of applications within 90 days](https://visa-processingtimes.homeoffice.gov.uk/y/accra-ghana/visits-visas/general-visit-6-months-or-less) so either they’re lying which is not surprising or they lost your passport.

The time for processing visa applications from Accra are shown below:

[image]

If you had paid the visa fee with a card I would have suggested you dispute the charge with your credit card processor.

What kind of background check for a visitor visa should take more than 3 months? This is nonsense and atrocious customer service. It’s not like they’re giving out visas to heaven or paradise.

Comment: Yeah I paid by credit card,  also have been advice to see immigration lawyer or complain to my foreign ministry

Comment: Immigration lawyer or your foreign ministry cannot do anything. By the way I am a Ghanaian myself, lived in Ghana the first 24 years of my life so I know how things work there. Void the transaction with your credit card company! By the way if you agree with my answer vote on it and if you believe it’s the best answer, accept it.